# Изменение пути к views для voyager

Tags: php, laravel-8, views

я решил использовать Voyager как админку в своём проекте. Столкнулся с проблемой, что модули и контроллеры можно легко переписать и создавать свои, но для видов нужно создавать подпапки `views/[vendor/voyager]/{route}/view.blade.php`.
Но у меня другая структура и мне нужно что бы пути были по типу: `views/Admin; Website/{route}/view.blade.php`.
Проблема в том, что я уже пытался найти что-то похожее, но всегда натыкался на то, что мне не нужно, запросы в браузере задавал и на русском и на английском.

Comment: И в чем же проблема? Каков вопрос? К - конкретика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартного апи для этого нету. Есть вариант с редактированием `VoyagerServiceProvider.php` (Что крайне не рекомендуется, ибо при обновлении вам нужно будет постоянно его редактировать ибо он ресетнится)

Код из `VoyagerServiceProvider.php`

```
...
public function boot(Router $router, Dispatcher $event)
    {
        if (config('voyager.user.add_default_role_on_register')) {
            $model = Auth::guard(app('VoyagerGuard'))->getProvider()->getModel();
            call_user_func($model.'::created', function ($user) use ($model) {
                if (is_null($user->role_id)) {
                    call_user_func($model.'::findOrFail', $user->id)
                        ->setRole(config('voyager.user.default_role'))
                        ->save();
                }
            });
        }

        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'voyager');
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        $router->aliasMiddleware('admin.user', VoyagerAdminMiddleware::class);

        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(realpath(__DIR__.'/../publishable/lang'), 'voyager');
...
```

После регистрации вьюшек самого `Voyager` мы можем зарегестрировать и свои.
Например

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(base_path('views/Admin/Website'), 'voyager');
```